# Shell script for postgres installation and restore db from remote client

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to install postgres 9.3 in ubuntu 12.04 (both client and server having same OS) from remote client (one system to another system using jcraft).

When i run the script below to the main system (using main systems's terminal, where i install the postgresql 9.3), it executes fine. Installation and creation of schema and restoring the database is done sucessfully.

But when i try to run the same script from remote client (using jcraft, i first upload the script to the system where i will install postgres, then run the script its showing some authentication error.

(FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")

Does somebody know what i'm doing wrong?

### Here is my script

```
PASS=dici

gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > ./pgdg.list

echo $PASS | sudo -S mv ./pgdg.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

echo $PASS | sudo -S apt-get update

echo $PASS |sudo -S apt-get -y -q install python-software-properties software-properties-common
echo $PASS |sudo -S apt-get -y --force-yes install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

echo "localhost:5432:*:postgres:postgres" >> .pgpass
echo $PASS | sudo -S chmod 600 .pgpass


echo $PASS|sudo -S su - postgres<<-'EOF'
 psql template1
 alter user postgres with password 'postgres';
 CREATE SCHEMA ayata AUTHORIZATION postgres;
 \q
 logout
EOF



echo $PASS | sudo -S chmod 777 /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf 

echo $PASS| sudo -S echo "host all  all  peer  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

echo $PASS | sudo -S chmod 777 /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

echo $PASS| sudo -S echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf


echo $PASS | sudo -S chmod 640 /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

echo $PASS | sudo -S chmod 644 /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

 echo $PASS| sudo -S service postgresql restart

echo "------------------ restore datatbase ----------------------------------------"
/usr/bin/pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --verbose "ayata.backup"
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Per my deleted answer I think you should be using a `.pgpass` file. You say the error persists with that, but to me I that suggests the file is in the wrong user's homedir or otherwise invalid. Without more info I can't really help and don't have the time for extended back and forth Q&A, so I'll leave this for someone else. Per advice in deleted answer, also use `sudo -u postgres` not `sudo su - postgres`.

Comment: Do you have a host with the unusual name of "peer"?  If not, what is that line in the pg_hba files supposed to be doing?

Comment: I solved the problem.....

Actually I need to comment the line 
"Host all all 127.0.01 md5"
"host  all  all ::1/128  md5"

and then append 

host  all  all  0.0.0.0/0 trust

Comment: I solved the problem.....

Actually I need to comment the line 
"Host all all 127.0.01 md5"
"host  all  all ::1/128  md5"

and then append 

host  all  all  0.0.0.0/0 trust
host  all  all ::1/128  trust
and then restart the server.

@Craig Ringer ...  .pgpass should be there.Thank for your help

Just doing this it worked outr for me....

Yesterday the first two line was not un-commented


Now I can configure a remote with installing postgresql from UI and restoring the database working fine....

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Argh, no, you *do not* need to add `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` - that's saying "completely disable all security for my database for all connections from anywhere".

Comment: yes you are right...
but we can put only the ip address where I am accessing the system...
I mean like host all  all 192.168.1.5/32 trust